# How to inclosed a code in a function

Tags: java, json, function, api, oop

This is my java code i am repeating the same steps for url and url1 so i want make a function in which i place the my url code seperate and url1 code seperate then call it in a main class. First I want to access String url and then I want to access String url1.As I am new in java so I am new in java so I am not able to enclose it into function

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Test_URL_Req {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {  
        String id ="301";
        String url = "https://tfs.tpsonline.com/IRIS%204.0%20Collection/Main/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=4.1";
           String url1 ="https://tfs.tpsonline.com/IRIS%204.0%20Collection/Main/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1&definitions=" + id +"&resultFilter=succeeded&$top=1";
         URL obj = new URL(url);
         URL obj1 = new URL(url1);
         HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
         HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) obj1.openConnection();
         int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
         int responseCode1 = con1.getResponseCode();
         System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
         System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
         System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url1);
         System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode1);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
         BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(con1.getInputStream()));
         String inputLine;
         String inputLine1;
         StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
            //System.out.println(response);
         }
         StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();
         while ((inputLine1 = in1.readLine()) != null) {
            response1.append(inputLine1);
            //System.out.println(response1);
         }
         in.close();

         JSONObject obj_JSONObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
         JSONObject obj_JSONObject1 = new JSONObject(response1.toString());
         JSONArray obj_JSONArray = obj_JSONObject.getJSONArray("value");
         JSONArray obj_JSONArray1 = obj_JSONObject1.getJSONArray("value");
        for(int i=0; i<obj_JSONArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj_JSONObject2 = obj_JSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String value = obj_JSONObject2.getString("name");
            //String value = obj_JSONObject2.get("id").toString();
            //System.out.println(value);

            String toSearch= "DEVOPS";
           if(value.equals(toSearch)){
                 System.out.println("STATUS:-");
                 System.out.println(value);
                 String result =obj_JSONObject2.getString("name");
                 System.out.println("BUILD NAME");
                 System.out.println(result);
                 String Def_id = obj_JSONObject2.get("id").toString();
                 System.out.println("DEFINATION ID");
                 System.out.println(Def_id);

                 break;

            }

        }

        for(int i=0; i<obj_JSONArray1.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj_JSONObject2 = obj_JSONArray1.getJSONObject(i);

            String value = obj_JSONObject2.getString("result");
            //String value = obj_JSONObject2.get("id").toString();
            //System.out.println(value);

            String toSearch1= "succeeded";
           if(value.equals(toSearch1)){
               System.out.println("#######################################");
                 System.out.println("RESULT");
                 System.out.println(value);

                 String result =obj_JSONObject2.getString("status");
                System.out.println("STATUS");
                 System.out.println(result);
                 String Def_id = obj_JSONObject2.get("id").toString();
                 System.out.println("BUILD ID");
                 System.out.println(Def_id);

                 boolean  keepForever =obj_JSONObject2.getBoolean("keepForever");

                if(keepForever == false)
                {
                    keepForever=true;
                }

                 System.out.println(keepForever);

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
           }

    }

}
```

Comment: Create a method and call it with the url as the argument?

Comment: `I am not able to enclose it into function` -> Why? What did you try?

Comment: Perhaps you should read a Java guide about methods, e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). Please be aware that StackOverflow is not a teaching site. You should try to learn Java on your own, e.g. by following tutorials on other sites, then come ask here if you have a *specific* problem. "Don't know how to create method" is **too broad**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static String getURLResponse( String url){
      try {
          System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
          URL obj = new URL(url);
          HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
          int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

          System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

          String inputLine;
          StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              response.append(inputLine);
              //System.out.println(response);
          }
          in.close();
        return  response.toString();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
      return null;
  }
```

In main method -

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            String url = "....";
            String url1 =".....";

            String response  = getURLResponse(url);
            String response1  = getURLResponse(url1);

            JSONObject obj_JSONObject = new JSONObject (response);
            JSONObject obj_JSONObject1 = new JSONObject(response1);
...
}
```

Comment: even the we can create one more function like :public  JSONArray  getJsonArray(String response){ 
   JSONObject obj_JSONObject = new JSONObject(response);
   return obj_JSONObject.getJSONArray("value");
  }

Comment: @FahadHaroon : you welcome. please accept and up vote the answer if it helps you so that other users can use it for refernece

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that takes a `String` and it appears you want a `StringBuffer` response...

```
public StringBuffer doSomething(String url){
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    //etc
    return response;
}
```

And just pass your two URLs to it from the main:

```
String url = "https://tfs.tpsonline...
StringBuffer response = doSomething(url);
```

Comment: can you make a function for a String Url